# Gems pre-installed on Project Creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I always dread creating a new project due to the amount of setup it sometimes requires. I have a number of Gems that I always use, some of which require additional configuration.

Now, I've done some research on the subject, and I can't seem to find anything about it, which,  I think,  is odd, since it would **benefit the flow** of **starting a new Rails Project**.

I suspect maybe that this has some broader Rails term that I haven't discovered yet.

So, is there a way to keep your favorite Gems (or any Gems) already installed and ready to go when you run the command:

```
rails new YourProject
```

**Update**

[Rails Appliaction Templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is not really suited for stackOverFlow. It's not a programming issue

Comment: It sure is a programming issue since **it keeps me** from **programming** and a an answer to it would greatly ease the flow of starting a new project.

Comment: You can't configure for this separate project with installed and configured gems. Start new project from that project. Too you can look at rails-composer and rails templates.

Comment: I'd like to know what takes you a good few hours, just to set a Rails project up.

Comment: I have rephrased the question for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no a *favorite gem* or something like that, but I have a template for the project creation process [`Rails Application Templates`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html), `railsrc.rb`:

```
gem 'awesome_print', require: false

gem_group :development do
  gem 'puma'
  gem 'pry-rails',          '~> 0.3.2'
  gem 'zeus'
end
gem_group :test do
  gem 'minitest-rails'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'ffaker', require: false
end
run "bundle install --path vendor/bundle"

#install minitest test_helper
generate 'mini_test:install'

environment "config.generators do |g|\n      g.test_framework :mini_test, spec: true, fixture: true\n    end"

# Add pride to minitest config
run "sed -i '' '4 s#^#require \"minitest/pride\"#' test/test_helper.rb"

#create postgres DB for postgress.app
#development and test
run "psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE #{app_path}_development;'"
run "psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE #{app_path}_test;'"

# add database yml
run "sed -i '' '4 s#^#require \"minitest/pride\"#' test/test_helper.rb"

#Add minitest features to Rake task
run %q^echo 'MiniTest::Rails::Testing.default_tasks << "features"' >> Rakefile^

#Fix README.md
run "rm README.rdoc"
run "touch README.md"

#Initialize local Git repository and Initial Commit
git :init
git add: "."
git commit: "-a -m 'Initial commit :pray:'"
```

Then I run `rails new my_awesome_app -m ~/railsrc.rb`, it build a brand new project with my requirements from `railsrc.rb`

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much.

Comment: Nice. It wasn't so easy to understand the question, and you did it just fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Bundler

[Bundler](http://bundler.io/) is the project you're looking for.

I'm not even sure how you can use Rails without it.

Once you have a `Gemfile` you like, it should take no more than 30 seconds to use the exact same gems for a new Rails project.

## Alternatives

Your question isn't clear, and you don't provide any example so it's hard to know what you're looking for. If you have a common base for all your Rails projects, you might consider [Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html), [git branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) or even whole virtual machines.

Comment: Of course I use bundler. But some gems require additional setup and changes to files as I'm sure you know.

Comment: So please mention it in the question.